# Tabelas dinâmicas com JQuery, JavaScript e Mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

Boa tarde amigos, estou com um problema, não estou conseguindo cadastrar todos os usuários no BD, só que apenas cadastra o último, como posso resolver esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Index

```
<form method="post" action="salvar.php">
```

Nome
      CPF
      Cargo - Função
      E-mail
      Parentesco
     Ações

```
  <select name="cargo">
         <option value="gerente" name="gerente">Gerente</option>
         <option value="Professor" name="Professor">Professor</option>
         <option value="Programador" name="Programador">Programador</option>
  </select>

  </td>


<td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
```

Remover
   
  
  
                
  
      
          Adicionar Dependentes
      
  
               
 
 Cadastrar

## salvar.php

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$parentesco = $_POST['parentesco'];




// faz consulta no banco para inserir os dados do usuario
$sql = "insert into cad_dependentes (nome, cpf, cargo, email, parentesco) values ('$nome', '$cpf', '$cargo', '$email', '$parentesco')";
```

## funcao.js

```
    (function($) {

  RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');

    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
      tr.remove(); 
    }); 

    return false;
  };

  AddTableRow = function() {

      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";

      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="nome"></td>';

      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="cpf"></td>'; 

      cols += '<td><select name="cargo">'; 
      cols += '<option value="gerente" name="gerente">Gerente</option>';
      cols += '<option value="Professor" name="Professor">Professor</option>';
      cols += '<option value="Programador" name="Programador">Programador</option>';
      cols += '</select></td>';

      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="email"></td>'; 

      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="parentesco"></td>'; 

      cols += '<td class="actions">';
      cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
      cols += '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);

      $("#products-table").append(newRow);

      return false;
  };


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente, para inserir múltiplos valores via formulário em PHP, você precisa definir um formato determinado para essa ação. Da forma que você fez, realmente sempre vai inserir apenas um arquivo.

Por exemplo, se eu tiver esses três inputs, sempre **o último valor** é que será enviado:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="submit" value="Submete Aí!">
</form>

<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

        var_dump($_POST['nome']);
    }
?>
```

O resultado seria:

[image: Resultado da submissão com PHP]

## Então, qual seria a forma de enviar um `array` por formulário?

Você precisa utilizar colchetes com o índice desejado, ou então os colchetes vazios, para a numeração dos índices sejam automáticias.

Veja:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome[]">
    <input type="text" name="nome[]">
    <input type="text" name="nome[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submete Aí!">
</form>

<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

        var_dump($_POST['nome']);
    }
?>
```

Nesse caso o resultado foi diferente:

[image: PHP submissão de um array]

Ainda você poderia numerar os índices do `array` no formulário, assim:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome[3]">
    <input type="text" name="nome[4]">
    <input type="text" name="nome[5]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submete Aí!">
</form>

<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

        var_dump($_POST['nome']);
    }
?>
```

O resultado seria:

[image: PHP submissão de formulário com array]

<sub>Note que no último exemplo, os índices `3`, `4` e `5` aparecem conforme definido no formulário.</sub>

No seu exemplo, eu nomearia cada índice via `jQuery`, deixando um nome reservado no `$_POST`, para facilitar a captura dos dados.

Exemplificando de forma simples, poderíamos ter:

```
 <form method="post">

    <input type="text" name="usuarios[0][nome]">
    <input type="text" name="usuarios[0][idade]">
    <input type="text" name="usuarios[0][email]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submete Aí!">
</form>

<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

        var_dump($_POST['usuarios']);
    }
?>
```

[image: Submissão de array com formulário em PHP (multidimensional)]

Sendo assim, poderíamos alterar o código Javascript que faz a criação dos inputs para a seguinte forma:

Veja:

```
var currentRow = 0;

AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+ currentRow + '][nome]"></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="cpf"></td>';

    cols += '<td><select name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][cargo]">';
    cols += '<option value="gerente" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][gerente]">Gerente</option>';
    cols += '<option value="Professor" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][Professor]">Professor</option>';
    cols += '<option value="Programador" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][Programador]">Programador</option>';
    cols += '</select></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][email]"></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="usuarios['+currentRow +'][parentesco]"></td>';

    cols += '<td class="actions">';
    cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);

    $("#products-table").append(newRow);

    ++currentRow;

    return false;
};
```

E seu script PHP que insere os dados, poderia ficar assim:

```
$pdo = Database::conexao(); 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO cad_dependentes (nome, cpf, cargo, email, parentesco) VALUES (:nome, :cpf, :cargo, :email, :parentesco)'); 

foreach ($_POST['usuarios'] as $usuario) { 

    $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $usuario['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':cpf', $usuario['cpf'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':cargo', $usuario['cargo'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $usuario['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':parentesco', $usuario['parentesco'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    
    $stmt->execute(); 

}
```

Note que eu apenas utilizei o `foreach` em `$_POST['usuarios']`. Fiz isso para ficar mais fácil e legível o que está sendo feito em cada linha inserida.

Cada linha inseria pelo seu jQuery, seria equivalente a isso:

```
<form method="post">

        <input type="text" name="usuarios[0][nome]">
        <input type="text" name="usuarios[0][idade]">
        <input type="text" name="usuarios[0][email]">
        <hr/>
        <input type="text" name="usuarios[1][nome]">
        <input type="text" name="usuarios[1][idade]">
        <input type="text" name="usuarios[1][email]">

    <input type="submit" value="Submete Aí!">
</form>

<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

        print_r($_POST['usuarios']);
    }
?>
```

Assim, veja o resultado:

[image: Submissão de formulário PHP (array multidimensional)]

Answer (score 5):

Bom, você precisa de um loop para fazer essa inserção, tente assim:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['nome']); $i++)
{
  $nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome'][$i]);
  $cpf = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cpf'][$i]);
  $cargo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cargo'][$i]);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'][$i]);
  $parentesco = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parentesco'][$i]);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO cad_dependentes (nome, cpf, cargo, email, parentesco) VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf', '$cargo', '$email', '$parentesco')") or die(mysql_error());
  echo "OK";
}
```

Altere o `name="cargo"` para `name="cargo[]"`, seguindo a dica do @Wallace Maxters

Dedique alguns minutos nessa pergunta : [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Meu amigo, na verdade o que está errado é a forma com que ele está criando os campos do formulário. Para você enviar mais de um dado via formulário, é necessário colocar o formato correto para isso. Ele colocou por exemplo o nome `name="gerente"` para cada campo. Pra funcionar da forma que você fez, ele teria que alterar todos os `"name"` dos inputs dinâmicos para "`name=gerente[]`"